# Can I supervise iphones with Apple Configurator 2 without MDM to get bypass codes for activation lock if needed?

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I work for a subsidiary company and our parent uses Microsoft Intune as an MDM and to use Office 365 mobile.  We've had some issues with departed employees returning factory locked iPhones either with a personal email AppleID or with a company email AppleID where the company mailbox has already been deleted.

I would like to be able to supervise the iPhones in some way that I can reset the phones, even when the original AppleID is no longer accessible.  I can't use MDM as I have minimal budget and have been advised by our corporate seller that iPhones can't have 2 MDMs at the same time.

I'm wondering (before I commit to buying a Mac Mini) whether I can use Apple Configurator 2 (or similar) to supervise the phones first, then set them up for the users as usual and deploy, such that I can either disable or bypass activation lock (I see some mention of a bypass code) should it be necessary.

(Our vendor has the option to enroll these phones into Apple Business Manager but they say that requires an MDM.)